# Matplotlib scatter plot how to give same color for same size

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am having two arrays and a difference arrays of first two arrays

```
X = [1, 5, 63, 77, 103, 148, 156, 177, 183]
Y = [3, 46, 65, 87, 129, 150, 166, 181, 186]
Diff  = [ 2 41  2 10 26  2 10  4  3  3]
```

How to plot a scatter plot for this data with x,y,diff where the same difference value show same color using matplotlib in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 'c' parameter to color the differences. 
Please see the below code:

```
X = [1, 5, 63, 77, 103, 148, 156, 177, 183]
Y = [3, 46, 65, 87, 129, 150, 166, 181, 186]
Diff  = [ 2, 41, 2, 10, 26, 2, 10, 4, 3] 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X,Y,c=Diff)
```

[image]